# numpy array assignment is slower than python list

Tags: python, numpy, benchmarking

numpy-

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
row = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
%timeit arr[0] = row
```

```
466 ns ± 12.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

python list -

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
row = [1, 2, 3, 4]
%timeit arr[0] = row
```

```
59.3 ns ± 2.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each
```

Shouldn't numpy be the faster version here?

---

Here's what I'm aiming to get done -

```
arr = np.empty((150, 4))

while True:
     row = get_row_from_api() 
     arr[-1] = row
```

Comment: Why should it be faster?

Comment: Well, here a list is re-assigning a *single* item, whereas in your `numpy.array` example, it is assigning 4 items. To get a fair comparison, you'd need something like `for i, x in enumerate(row): arr[0][i] = x`

Comment: Ah, is there any way to make numpy do the former?

Comment: @DevAggarwal no, why would you *want it to*? You could use a `numpy.ndarray` object with `dtype=object`, but then you are essentially working with a bad list. So at that point, just use a `list` instead of a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Because I want my program to run faster? And I've identified this as a critical part of my code?

Comment: @DevAggarwal do you understand the semantic difference between the two things going on? Are you sure that your overall program will be faster if you switch to a `list` object to represent whatever data you are processing? It may be. But without more information, it's hard to tell. What is the nature of the data you are working with, and the operations you are doing with it?

Comment: I'm processing stock market data, and I'd like to have a contiguous array of `n` candles (last one being the live candle). The ticks arrive at sub-second intervals. Multiply that across 5000 stocks, and I have a problem

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example, with a more realistic context? Again, there are pretty significant differences between a `list` and a `numpy.ndarray`.  And it isn't immediately obvious exactly what you are doing with your numpy array.

Comment: Does it make any sense now?

Comment: Are you trying to append or fill in the array with `arr[-1] = row`

Comment: fill existing index, not append

Comment: `arr[-1] = row` repeatedly assigns a value to the same **last** row of `arr`.  It does not 'step-through' the rows,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, using python lists this way would definitely be faster, because when you assign something to a python list element, it's not copied, just some references are reassigned (https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists). Numpy instead copies all the elements from the source container to the target one. I'm not sure whether you need numpy arrays here, because their creation is not free and python lists aren't that slow at creation (and as we see at assignment as well).

Comment: Ah, there's a bit of code down the chain that uses numpy, not sure if its worth doing the conversion from list -> numpy everytime

Comment: I think it's better to check the whole sequence of operations for its performance in total. It's difficult to say a priori what's going to work faster (unless you're not multiplying [1000, 1000] matrices or doing something like that).

Comment: @DevAggarwal Maybe time the whole chain instead of just the numpy versus list snipped and see what works best. Numpy should be faster on *calculations*. How complex are yours down the chain?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying semantics of the two operations are very different. Python lists are arrays of references. Numpy arrays are arrays of the data itself.

The line `row = get_row_from_api()` implies that a fresh list has already been allocated.

Assigning to a list as `lst[-1] = row` just writes an address into `lst`. That's generally 4 or 8 bytes.

Placing in an array as `arr[i] = row` is copying data. It's a shorthand for `arr[i, :] = row`. Every element of `row` gets copied to the buffer of `arr`. If `row` was a list, that incurs additional overhead to convert from python objects to native numerical types.

Remember that premature optimization is pointless. Your time savings for one method vs the other are likely to be negligible. At the same time, if you need an array later down the line anyway, it's likely faster to pre-allocate and take a small speed hit rather than calling `np.array` on the final list. In the former case, you allocate a buffer of predetermined size and dtype. In the latter, you've merely deferred the overhead of copying the data, but also incurred the overhead of having to figure out the array size and dtype.